# How to sign XML document or verify XML document signature in Android

Tags: android, xml

I am looking for way, how to sign XML document I have currently in Assets. I need to sign it, and then, when I download it over HTTP, I need to verify its signature. Is there some simple way how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way for XML signing on Android. The usual code for XML signing that works on regular Java does not work on Android because of differences in padding initialization.
After weeks of trying and testing I have managed to do manual XML signing on android.
See the answer on this question [XML SOAP Signing on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991290/xml-soap-signing-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could try PGP for a signature and encryption.